# Why isn't he fetchXml count attribute limiting the records returned?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have a javascript function that adds a custom view to a control using fetchXML. My issue is that the count attribute on the root `<fetch>` node is not working.  I have it set to 6, but it's returning 26 records (all of the records), defined by the fetch.

Here is the fetchXML

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' count='6'>
  <entity name='xyz_entity'>
    <attribute name='xyz_entityname' />
    <attribute name='xyz_startdate' />
    <attribute name='xyz_enddate' />
    <attribute name='xyz_currententity' />
    <attribute name='xyz_inactiveentity' />
    <order attribute='xyz_currententity' descending='true' />
    <order attribute='xyz_startdate' />
    <filter type='or'>
      <condition attribute='xyz_currententity' operator='eq' value='1' />
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='xyz_startdate' operator='ge' value='2011-11-01' />
        <condition attribute='xyz_enddate' operator='gt' value='2011-11-01' />
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

And the fetchXML is being used in the javscript like this:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("itt_termid").addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
```

but when the user clicks on the lookup icon, all 26, rather than 6 records get returned.

Comment: I've had trouble finding any documentation on the count attribute, but it seems it is _supposed_ to work like a Select Top

Comment: @codeulike - It's an actual bug.  Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7987277/227436, click on the link and scroll to the very bottom.  It was supposed to be fixed in rollup 10, but they're pretty good at pushing stuff back, and I haven't bothered to test it since then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can specify how many records they want to appear per page, and since the control has to do paging of its own, my guess would be that it's replacing your count with its own. If you run this fetch outside of the context of a lookup view, does it correctly limit the count?

Comment: What's the easiest way to do that?  This is my first time working with CRM

Comment: Harris-Tech have a good blog about creating custom views for lookups - I think you could follow along: http://www.harris-tech.com/blogs/bid/54720/Creating-Filtered-Lookups-in-CRM-2011

Comment: @Daryl The easiest way would be to download Stunnware tools (http://www.stunnware.com/products/tools4/download.htm) and hook that up to your environment to test. The tools were originally designed for CRM 4, but they also work against CRM 2011.

Comment: My fetch works correctly in stunnware.  Although I truly believe this to be a bug in CRM 2011, I'm awarding @Matt the answer for the stunnware suggestion.  It truly was the information I needed to answer my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like besides ignoring the count of the fetch XML, the custom view also ignores any Ordering

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried explicitly specifying the page number (as 1) ?

Something like

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'     page='1' count='6'>
```

Comment: As @Matt says in his answer, have you tried running this outside the context of a lookup view to see if the correct number of results are returned?

Comment: I was getting the same issue and setting the page number resolved it.

Comment: This solved my issue.  Thanks. I was using JavaScript and XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch("Fetch XML"); I used the top and count attributes alone, top and page together and the only combination that worked was using both count and page attributes.  Interestingly enough, all options work in the 'FetchXML Tester' in the XrmToolBox.  This is in CRM 2016.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the Custom Views for CRM 2011.  It also doesn't support order by as referenced by this page: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/81537133-b3a7-457b-a257-b745b30ca98e